# What's the best way to wait for a Form to be closed in MS Access VBA?

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, wait

I call a Form from a module, and would like to wait for the Form to be closed before completing the rest of that module.  What is a proper way to do the waiting?

I have an *IsOpen("formname")* function to check to see if the Form is still open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set `WindowMode:=acDialog` when you initiate `DoCmd.OpenForm`

Here is how it is done from other Office VBA (Excel, Word, VB6, VB.Net)
Call the form modally using the following code

```
Dim f as new FormNameHere
f.Show True  'True is the option for Dialog in VB
' form will be displayed until the user dismisses it then execution continues
set f = Nothing
```

Otherwise:

```
f.ShowDialog
```

Comment: That led me to the answer.  I'm using the DoCmd.OpenForm, so I need to set WindowMode:=acDialog.  If you edit this in your answer, I'll accept.  Thanks.

Comment: This is a terribly formatted answer, as everything after the first line is completely irrelevant to Access.